# Resuming a Jenkins job post re-imaging of a slave computer

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

Basically, I'm running a Jenkins master server on my computer and I follow the current process:

I call a job to execute a batch file on my slave node computer which re-images the entire computer.

How can I set-up Jenkins so that once the slave node has been re-imaged, it contacts the **Master** and then does a specific job which it should do depending on a configuration which was decided at the time of execution of the first job?

An ideal solution would let me simply configure the job to execute a particular .exe file on a slave machine once it's done re-imaging.

Example:

```
    Slave\ReImage.bat
    <the slave node reimages itself here>
    <it connects back to Jenkins via a batch file in the system startup (JNLP)>

Now what I want is for it to execute say:
    program.exe file2use.csv
```

on this very machine as soon as the machine is done reimaging, starting up and launching the JNLP agent on the slave node. The process should be automated and ideally, only require setting up the job at the beginning and hitting 'build' for the whole procedure to finish.

The Jenkins website is undergoing rework on some pages right now, so documentation is hard to find. If there is a solid way to do this with the pipeline plugin, let me know.
Any help or advice on this would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how quickly the agent goes offline after running the batch script, you could likely do something like this with Pipeline:

```groovy
// Run tasks on the target agent
node('agent') {
    // Get the scripts
    git 'https://example.com/reimage-scripts.git'

    // Re-image this machine
    bat 'reimage'
}

// Give the agent a chance to go offline;
// this doesn't need an agent to run on
sleep 30

// Run more tasks on the agent; this will block until it's online again
node('agent') {
    // Get the scripts
    git 'https://example.com/reimage-scripts.git'

    // Run the setup program
    bat 'program.exe file2use.csv'
}
```

If you want something smarter than "sleep for a bit", you could likely replace that with something like:

```groovy
// Watch from another machine until the agent goes offline
node('master') {
    bat 'ping-agent-until-it-goes-offline'
}
```